# Numerically solving an initial value problem on an unbounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I wish to solve the pde:
$$-\frac{1}{1-t}\partial_x^2\phi+t^4(1-t)\partial_t^2\phi-t^4\partial_t\phi=\mu^2 \phi,$$
with initial conditions $\phi(x,0)=\cos(\mu x)$ and $\dot{\phi}(x,0)=0$ for some time period $t\in[0,0.9]$, for example. Lacking analytical methods (separation of variables was not fruitful), I thought I'd try numerically. However, numerically means I have to give a solver a spacial domain $[-a,a]$ on which to solve... and I have no idea what boundary conditions to impose on $x=\pm a$. In a sense, the value of $\phi$ on spacial slices like $x=a$ are exactly what I'm trying to find in the first place!

How does one treat such problems numerically?

Comment: Perhaps, since the initial condition is periodic, I could impose periodic boundary conditions to get away with it? The question still remains for generic initial conditions.

Comment: If you have any information on the asymptotic behavior of $\phi$ as $|x|\to \infty$, you can consider a large value for $a$ and use the  asymptotic condition as the actual value on the boundary.

Comment: I don't unfortunately. I found a paper that treats this sort of problem. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0168-9274(98)00025-7